# on click make SVG resizable

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-ui-resizable

How to set SVG resizable "on click" by jQuery UI ?

[**jsfiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/4ku6a5ub/)

HTML

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" x="0.00000000" y="0.00000000" width="480.00000" height="480.00000"  id="svg1">
    <path d="M 574.28571 350.93362 A 230.00000 230.00000 0 1 1  114.28571,350.93362 A 230.00000 230.00000 0 1 1  574.28571 350.93362 z" transform="translate(-95.71429,-108.5714)" style="opacity:1.0000000;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1.0000000;stroke:none;stroke-width:2.0000000;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4.0000000;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1.0000000" id="path1366" />
    <path d="M 231.48189,473.26283 C 131.83469,468.06658 42.098062,390.44395 21.653942,292.99899 C 2.8527423,211.64305 32.299602,121.62080 96.083632,67.582430 C 141.33822,28.222080 202.15620,7.4760400 262.06397,11.991470 C 356.93917,15.843450 443.80335,86.158270 469.35800,177.35283 C 479.83354,210.86634 479.80411,246.84493 475.57362,281.36221 C 461.15785,369.25654 392.02150,445.16887 305.33917,466.41185 C 281.37157,472.30240 256.12409,475.36915 231.48189,473.26283 z M 195.98189,459.07832 C 153.70976,438.32840 127.57657,390.25793 133.57107,343.48796 C 138.36082,288.35497 188.51696,242.79478 243.64749,241.80851 C 289.80353,243.23178 335.32348,214.53137 352.09275,171.21770 C 372.17245,123.85997 354.81639,64.420260 312.15547,35.497910 C 277.18597,9.7192000 230.39701,15.186720 190.59735,24.146350 C 98.599342,46.695330 27.467842,132.85978 22.328202,227.37156 C 15.617372,312.66393 62.578582,398.76397 137.71937,439.58565 C 156.53626,449.74840 183.25724,461.62547 200.86096,461.86871 L 198.91377,460.67719 L 195.98190,459.07832 L 195.98189,459.07832 z M 240.98189,156.44487 C 217.68690,151.96726 210.63785,117.76008 230.72475,104.79451 C 251.31111,88.759900 283.63841,110.57202 275.52356,135.98196 C 271.79700,150.60792 255.61257,159.83414 240.98189,156.44487 z M 252.66158,383.23027 C 281.22410,379.65834 281.98701,333.88297 253.46715,329.56000 C 230.89663,323.64667 211.28225,351.85522 224.59048,371.08172 C 230.24130,379.64095 242.27756,386.42957 252.66158,383.23027 z " style="fill:#000000" id="path1351" />
</svg>
```

jQUERY

```
 $('#svg1').click(function () {
     $("#svg1").resizable();
 });
```

---

[**SOLUTION**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/bf3zck06/1/)  from Alvin.K

Comment: Resizable() works on the `<div>`, see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331091/jquery-ui-resizable-resizing-doesnt-work-for-dynamically-created-svg-element), for SVG you have to write some coding to change `width`, `height` and `viewBox` base on mouseX,Y position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331091/jquery-ui-resizable-resizing-doesnt-work-for-dynamically-created-svg-element) in the comment above, you can try this tweak, doesn't change the SVG, only the DIV size.

```
    $('body').append('<div style="width:200px; height:200px; 
      border:solid thin #888; padding:0px; border-radius:4px; 
      background-color:#ccc;">');

    var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "svg");
    svg.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", "0 0 200 200");
    $('div').append(svg);

    var square = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "rect");
    square.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "200");
    square.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "200");
    square.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "0");
    square.setAttributeNS(null, "y", "0");
    square.setAttributeNS(null, "style", "fill:#FF0000");
    $('svg').append(square);

    $('div').draggable({
        handle: 'rect'
    }).resizable({
        aspectRatio: 1.0
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this , but.... it does not resize SVG image. http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/bf3zck06/

Comment: Missing `viewbox`, add to the the line `id="svg3" viewbox="0 0 500 500" >`. Try changing the `width="100%"` and `height="100%"` in the `svg` also.

Comment: Typo: it should be `viewBox` as SVG is case sensitive