# Scaling a circle in SVG

Tags: svg

I have the following SVG code. To scale the circle only, I have to scale the container. I can't scale the circle inside the SVG.

I can access the circle element, but why can't I like other html elements? Is the code scaling the circle or the container?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function scale() {
            document.getElementById('container').setAttribute('currentScale', 1.5);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <svg height="150" width="150" id="container">
        <circle cx="25" r="20" cy="20" fill="blue" id="circle"></circle>
    </svg>
    <button id="zoom" onclick="scale()">scale</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solution is very similar this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279031/on-click-make-svg-resizable/25295895) which is to wrap it around a DIV and use CSS on this DIV

Comment: I don't understand your question or expectation. You can scale the circle in SVG by applying a scale transform to the element. Create a test case at http://jsfiddle.net showing what you tried to do that didn't work.

Comment: I created the code in jsfiddle. However I can't see the result that I see in my regular browser. Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/hb4nnau0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never tried scaling the whole SVG (using the pure SVG transform attribute). But look like you can just scale each element inside SVG. In this case you have to target (select) the circle first before calling `setAttribute` on it to modify the `transform` attribute to `scale(1.5,1.5)` like this:

```
function scale() {
  document.querySelector("#container > circle")
          .setAttribute('transform', 'scale(1.5,1.5)');    
}
```

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hb4nnau0/2/). Note that you have to select the option `No Wrap - in <head>` (on the right hand in the **Frameworks & Extensions** section). Or better you should attach click handler right in JS code editor (not inline as an attribute in HTML code).

Comment: Yup, hard-setting the attribute as a string works, too.

Comment: @Phrogz in fact the first book I read about SVG just introduces this kind of *scripting* to script SVG. Your code is also new to me. If you know some book about that, I would be happy to know some title. (I prefer reading offline book to surfing net online).

Comment: Sorry, I am the opposite: I dislike offline (out of date, unsearchable, dead-tree) books, so I don't know any. For more details, SVG elements have their own DOM. I have it lightly recorded at ObjJob, e.g. if you click on "Show inherited properties/methods?" for [`<circle/>`](http://objjob.phrogz.net/svg/object/27) you will see that it has a `transform` property that is a `SVGAnimatedTransformList`; click on that to see what properties it has. Or, go read the [specs from the source](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/svgdom.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to scale just the circle using JS:

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hb4nnau0/1/

1. For convenience, give your circle a `transform` attribute with no change in scale added. (Alternatively you can add this programmatically on demand.)
   `
2. In your event handler, modify the scale of this transform element:

   ```
   var circle = document.querySelector('circle');   // Or however, e.g. by id
   var scale = circle.transform.animVal.getItem(0); // The first transform
   scale.setScale(4,3);                             // Modify the transform
   ```

Comment: Thanks for responding. However, I was not able to see the demo working. It does not scale. I tested this in IE11 and Crome.