# How to scale an image based on its container div size using Raphael without distorting the image

Tags: svg, raphael

Hi I am trying to include an image in a div. and I want to scale it based on the size of its container div (not window size). I also don't want to change the shape of the image. I tried to use scale.raphael.js but that din't help me. Can some one please guide me how can I achieve that. Thanks in advance

Comment: May help if you can put it on a jsfiddle. You may want to set the svg size to be 100%,100% and preserveAspectRatio https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Comment: Don't need Raphael, plain old jQuery UI will work, answer found in this [SO solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279031/on-click-make-svg-resizable/25295895). Update the `aspectRatio: 1.0` to your image ratio.