# multiple svg layered on canvas, let svg moveable and resizeable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

As we can see, a `div` can be draggable, resizeable using javascript. 
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

`svg` is also a `html` element, 
Is it possible that I use `css`+ `jquery` to drag, resize the svg.

Here, svg is the whole svg, not the children of svg elements.

I know if I can use group of svg element(`g`) to translate. But the svg is not changed, position is not changed.

I tried set `left`, `top`. 
I also tried set `x`, `y`.

```
 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                   .attr("left", 200)
                                   .attr("top", 200);
                                   .attr("width", 200)
                                   .attr("height", 200);



var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                           .attr("x", 200)
                           .attr("y", 200);
                           .attr("width", 200)
                           .attr("height", 200);
```

Is it possible to make it draggable and resizeable?

**`Div` is an DOM element, it can be resizable, dragable.**

**`svg` is also a Dom element, can it be resizeable and dragable?**

Although, I still has above question, thanks `Alvin K`: it solves my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/bf3zck06/1/

thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [on click make SVG resizable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279031/on-click-make-svg-resizable)

Comment: And maybe this: stackoverflow.com/q/11524263/2472391

Comment: thanks, @AlvinK. Unfortunately, they are use translate to translate the children of svg element. I want to change svg. not It's children. Because I layered svg on canvas, if svg is not moved, when my mouse put on that place it is not on svg not on canvas. But if it is move it should be on canvas.

Comment: thanks, @AlvinK it seems you are right, you put the svg in the div and it can moveable. Although the x , y of svg is not changed. the div is chaging, thanks, I Got that.

Answer (score 0):

A demo for scale and drag: http://plnkr.co/edit/sSXYpwjvVB8m1GVuE40A?p=preview
    var svg = d3.select("#chart1").append('svg');

```
svg.attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 200)
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 200 200");

var circle = svg.append('circle')
  .attr({
    r: 30,
    cx: 100,
    cy: 100
  })
  .style({
    fill: "green",
    stroke: "red"
  });
var open = false;
circle.on('click', function(e) {
  open = !open;
  if (open) {
    svg.attr("viewBox", "0 0 200 200");
  } else {
    svg.attr("viewBox", "0 0 400 400");
  }
})


 circle.on("mousemove", function() {
  circle.attr("cx", d3.mouse(this)[0]);
  circle.attr("cy", d3.mouse(this)[1]);
});
```

Yes, you should be able to work it just as other DOM.

If you are using d3, d3 is full capable for the resize and scale.  no need to involve jQuery to make things more complicated.  You could attach your code in  jsbin or plunker

BTW, You need to get to know the different of d3selection.attr and d3selection.style.

attr is used for attribute pairs

style is used for css style.

In the browser war days, they are kind of mess up, but now, we have much better standard for this.

Comment: Thanks, but your example is just moving the elements of svg. But the svg is still is the left corner. I do not want to move element of svg. I just want to move the all svg. just like div. From the jQuery example, if you move the div will change left top. or resize: width, height