# Scaling SVG with fixed dimensions

Tags: html, css, svg

I came across this super cool demo of a SVG rocket getting ready to blast off.

http://jsfiddle.net/timrpeterson/4FMyA/22/

first line of the JSFiddle:

```
<svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="307px" height="283px" id="rocket">
```

I know the point of SVG is to be "scalable" but I just realized I have no idea how this is done. I'd like to shrink the entire rocket and circle surrounding it by 75%, but it looks like everything has defined dimensions.

Is there a simple way to shrink everything the same amount or do I have to manually scale each value?

Comment: Tweak of this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279031/on-click-make-svg-resizable/25295895), to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alkhoo/bf3zck06/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make it like this:

Remove width and height from the svg, add a [viewbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) with the width/height attributes, add an [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) attribute with "xMinYMin meet" value and then absolute position the svg inside a relative positioned div with width: 100% and max-width that you want the element to be. The last part is the padding-bottom value that serves us as the aspect ratio when we resize the svg element. Long story short this is it.

**Change the max-width value of .svg-container to see the svg scale :)** Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timrpeterson/4FMyA/26/

```css
/*=============================================
[ Page Setup ]
==============================================*/

body {
  background: #34495e
}
#pageWrap {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.svg-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 64%;
}
#rocket {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
/*=============================================
[ Inactive State Styles ]
==============================================*/

.rocket_inner {
  transform: translateY(15px) translateX(-3px);
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
.icon_circle {
  transition: .2s;
  fill: #22303e;
}
.large_window_path {
  transition: .2s;
  fill: #22303e;
}
.small_window_path {
  fill: #22303e;
}
.wing_shadow {
  fill: #34495e;
}
.rocket_bottom {
  fill: #34495e
}
.rocket_base {
  fill: #34495e
}
.rocket_shadow {
  fill: #34495e
}
.window_grandient {
  stop-color: #2DCB73
}
.window_grandient1 {
  stop-color: #2AC16D
}
.window_grandient2 {
  stop-color: #29B968
}
.window_grandient3 {
  stop-color: #28B767
}
.wing_base {
  fill: #34495e
}
.fire_path {
  fill: #FC0
}
/*=============================================
[ Hover Styles ]
==============================================*/

.rocket_wrap:hover .rocket_base {
  fill: #FFFFFF !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}
.rocket_wrap:hover .rocket_shadow {
  fill: #EDEDED !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}
.rocket_wrap:hover .icon_circle {
  fill: #282e3a !important;
  stroke: #fff !important;
  stroke-width: 7px !important;
}
.rocket_wrap:hover .small_window_path {
  fill: #28B767 !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}
.rocket_wrap:hover .wing_shadow {
  display: block !important;
  fill: #FC9252 !important;
}
.rocket_wrap:hover .wing_base {
  fill: #E16E36 !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}
.rocket_wrap:hover .rocket_bottom {
  fill: #2DCB73 !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}
.rocket_wrap:hover .large_window_path {
  fill: url(#SVGID_2_) !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}
.rocket_wrap:hover .rocket_inner {
  transform: translateY(0px) translateX(-3px) !important;
}
/*=============================================
[ Animation Classes ]
==============================================*/

.fire {
  display: none;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  stroke-width: 0px;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-direction: normal;
}
.rocket_wrap:hover #fireLeft {
  display: block;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: fireLeft, fillOpacity1;
  animation-duration: 1.2s;
}
.rocket_wrap:hover #fireMiddle {
  display: block;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: fireMiddle, fillOpacity1;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
.rocket_wrap:hover #fireRight {
  display: block;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: fireRight, fillOpacity1;
  animation-duration: 1.3s;
}
.rocket_wrap:hover #fireSmallLeft {
  display: block;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: fireSmall, fillOpacity2;
  animation-duration: 1.3s;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
.rocket_wrap:hover #fireSmallRight {
  display: block;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-name: fireSmall, fillOpacity3;
  animation-duration: 1.6s;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
/*=============================================
[ KeyFrame Animations ]
==============================================*/

@keyframes fireSmall {
  10% {
    transform: rotate(17deg) translateY(1px)
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(-13deg) translateY(2px)
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(21deg) translateY(3px)
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-34deg)translateY(4px)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(24deg) translateY(5px)
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(-17deg) translateY(6px)
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(31deg) translateY(7px)
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-28deg) translateY(8px)
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(14deg) translateY(9px)
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(10px)
  }
}
@keyframes fireLeft {
  6% {
    transform: rotate(25deg)
  }
  15% {
    transform: rotate(-19deg)
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(25deg)
  }
  32% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg)
  }
  46% {
    transform: rotate(22deg)
  }
  54% {
    transform: rotate(-29deg)
  }
  61% {
    transform: rotate(32deg)
  }
  74% {
    transform: rotate(-9deg)
  }
  83% {
    transform: rotate(16deg)
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}
@keyframes fireMiddle {
  10% {
    transform: rotate(25deg)
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(-25deg)
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(30deg)
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-22deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(29deg)
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg)
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(37deg)
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg)
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(16deg)
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}
@keyframes fireRight {
  15% {
    transform: rotate(17deg)
  }
  23% {
    transform: rotate(-13deg)
  }
  37% {
    transform: rotate(21deg)
  }
  45% {
    transform: rotate(-34deg)
  }
  54% {
    transform: rotate(24deg)
  }
  67% {
    transform: rotate(-17deg)
  }
  72% {
    transform: rotate(31deg)
  }
  84% {
    transform: rotate(-28deg)
  }
  96% {
    transform: rotate(14deg)
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}
@keyframes fillOpacity1 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fillOpacity2 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fillOpacity3 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  67% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes rocektMove {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(20px)
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- http://www.pencilscoop.com/2013/11/animate-svg-icons-with-css3-jquery/ -->
<div id="pageWrap">
  <div class="svg-container">
    <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 307 283" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" id="rocket">
      <g class="rocket_wrap">
        <circle cx="147.5" cy="138.6" r="105.5" class="icon_circle" />
        <g class="rocket_inner">
          <path class="fire fire_path" id="fireMiddle" d="M148.891,179.906c3.928,0,7.111,3.176,7.111,7.094 c0,7.78-7.111,16-7.111,16s-7.111-8.349-7.111-16C141.78,183.082,144.963,179.906,148.891,179.906z" />
          <path class="fire_path fire" id="fireRight" d="M154.063,181.092c3.577-1.624,7.788-0.048,9.408,3.52 c3.216,7.084,0.139,17.508,0.139,17.508s-9.927-4.662-13.09-11.63C148.9,186.923,150.487,182.715,154.063,181.092z" />
          <path class="fire_path fire" id="fireLeft" d="M143.392,182.519c3.25,2.207,4.098,6.623,1.896,9.864 c-4.372,6.436-14.873,9.238-14.873,9.238s-1.191-10.902,3.108-17.23C135.725,181.149,140.143,180.312,143.392,182.519z" />
          <path class="fire_path fire" id="fireSmallLeft" d="M143.193 187.531c2.226 0.4 3.7 2.6 3.2 4.8 c-0.875 4.407-5.829 8.264-5.829 8.264s-3.09-5.53-2.229-9.865C138.807 188.5 141 187.1 143.2 187.531z" />
          <path class="fire_path fire" id="fireSmallRight" d="M152.089 188.599c2.043-0.985 4.496-0.132 5.5 1.9 c1.952 4 0.3 10.1 0.3 10.107s-5.795-2.56-7.713-6.541C149.186 192 150 189.6 152.1 188.599z" />
          <path class="rocket_bottom" d="M157.069 171.31h-3.292c-1.562-0.048-3.178-0.076-4.846-0.076 s-3.284 0.028-4.846 0.076h-3.292c-7.277-7.938-12.371-26.182-12.371-47.434c0-28.54 9.182-51.676 20.508-51.676 c11.327 0 20.5 23.1 20.5 51.676C169.44 145.1 164.3 163.4 157.1 171.31z"
          />
          <g id="right_wing_wrap">
            <path class="wing_base" d="M166.678 127.161c0 0 17.7 3.3 12.9 48.099l-18.06-14.05 L166.678 127.161z" />
            <path class="wing_shadow" d="M158.225 140.336c10.481-5.584 22.7 22.2 21.4 34.9 l-18.06-14.05C161.542 161.2 156.1 144.3 158.2 140.336z" />
          </g>
          <g id="left_wing_wrap">
            <path class="wing_base" d="M135.131 161.21l-18.06 14.1 c-4.805-44.793 12.924-48.099 12.924-48.099L135.131 161.21z" />
            <path class="wing_shadow" d="M135.131 161.21l-18.06 14.1 c-1.367-12.746 10.896-40.509 21.377-34.924C140.614 144.3 135.1 161.2 135.1 161.21z" />
          </g>
          <g id="rocket_body_wrap">
            <path class="rocket_base" d="M162.728 167.358c-3.778-0.623-8.573-0.996-13.796-0.996 s-10.018 0.373-13.795 0.996c-5.033-10.186-8.257-25.808-8.257-43.338c0-30.688 9.873-55.566 22.052-55.566 s22.053 24.9 22.1 55.566C170.984 141.6 167.8 157.2 162.7 167.358z"
            />
            <path class="rocket_shadow" d="M145.464 166.417c19.578-40.575 7.26-85.229 4.112-98.067 c11.88 0.9 21.4 25.4 21.4 55.525c0 17.529-3.225 33.152-8.257 43.337c0 0-3.786-0.472-8.069-0.697 S145.464 166.4 145.5 166.417z" />
          </g>
          <g id="large_window_wrap">
            <radialgradient id="SVGID_2_" cx="148.9" cy="112.5" r="15.2" fx="139.4853" fy="112.5239" gradientunits="userSpaceOnUse">
              <stop offset="0" class="window_grandient" />
              <stop offset="0.5868" class="window_grandient" />
              <stop offset="0.6834" class="window_grandient" />
              <stop offset="0.6845" class="window_grandient1" />
              <stop offset="0.6861" class="window_grandient2" />
              <stop offset="0.6897" class="window_grandient3" />
            </radialgradient>
            <circle class="large_window_path" cx="148.9" cy="111.3" r="10.5" />
          </g>
          <circle class="small_window_path" cx="148.9" cy="132.4" r="5.2" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```